# where can i find nginx (stable) for docker?

Tags: docker, nginx

i'm trying to make a dockerfile that contains Nginx stable latest compiled with vts module .... there is a big problem i'm having that i can't find some automotive link when i put in the docker file it will download and install the latest stable nginx i can only specify a version like 1.14.2 is there a way i can modify my dockerfile to make it download the latest always and not only one version ?

this is my dockerfile

```
FROM debian:stretch-slim




RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y git wget libreadline-dev libncurses5-dev libpcre3-    dev libssl-dev perl make build-essential zlib1g-dev && \
    cd /tmp/ && \
    wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.14.2.tar.gz && \
    git clone git://github.com/vozlt/nginx-module-vts.git && \
    tar zxvf nginx-1.14.2.tar.gz && \
    rm -f nginx-1.14.2.tar.gz && \
    cd nginx-1.14.2 && \
    ./configure --prefix=/tmp/nginx-1.14.2 --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --    modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
    --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid \
    --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-    path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-    path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp \
    --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-    temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-    path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp \
    --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-compat --with-file-aio --with-    threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module \
    --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-    http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module \
    --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-    http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module \
    --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-    http_v2_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream \
    --with-stream_realip_module --with-stream_ssl_module --with-    stream_ssl_preread_module \
    --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/data/builder/debuild/nginx-    1.14.2/debian/debuild-base/nginx-1.14.2=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-    compile.specs -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -    Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC' \
    --with-ld-opt='-specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-link.specs -Wl,-z,relro -    Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -pie' \
    --add-module=/tmp/nginx-module-vts && \
    make && make install && \
    cp -f objs/nginx /usr/sbin/nginx && \
    apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for an easy way to keep using the stable version during compiling nginx from source as there is no one direct url for it afaik, then you can pass a [build argument](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg) to your Dockerfile like this:

```
...
ARG NGINX_STABLE_VERSION
RUN   wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-${NGINX_STABLE_VERSION}.tar.gz
...
```

And run the build command like below to keep downloading nginx version based on the passed argument:

```
docker build --build-arg NGINX_STABLE_VERSION=1.14.2 .
```

However if you are look for how to keep using the official docker image for nginx with your custom modules - **assuming all the custom modules you are using support dynamic modules feature like vts module** - then you can do it by using [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build) and make use of nginx [dynamic modules](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/dynamic-modules/dynamic-modules/)
 feature.

According to [nginx-module-vts changelog](https://github.com/vozlt/nginx-module-vts/blob/master/Changes#L101) there is a support for compiling the module as a dynamic module so you can do a multi-stage build that compile nginx with the module you want then copy the generated file to nginx image with the same version to make it work.

Nginx stable images can be found in [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx?tab=tags) tagged with `stable` word.

All you need to do now is to modify the Dockerfile and make it use the dynamic modules way then add another stage for using the stable image with the new module that was generated from the first stage and you can add an argument during the build for example:

```
...
ARG NGINX_STABLE_VERSION
RUN   wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-${NGINX_STABLE_VERSION}.tar.gz
...
```

And run the build like this:

```
docker build --build-arg NGINX_STABLE_VERSION=1.14.2 .
```

---

**Update:**

Nginx does not provide a one link that you can use to get the stable version every time so you might go with parsing the html of the download page like the following to keep getting the latest download link for the stable version:

> We rely on the HTML page which is not the most robust solution on the long term.

```
echo "http://nginx.org$(curl -s http://nginx.org/en/download.html | grep -oP 'Stable version.*?\K(/download/.*?tar.gz)')"
```

Output:

```
http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.14.2.tar.gz
```

In your Dockerfile it can be like this:

> Make sure that you have curl installed

```
RUN curl "http://nginx.org$(curl -s http://nginx.org/en/download.html | grep -oP 'Stable version.*?\K(/download/.*?tar.gz)')" --output nginx.tar.gz
```

Comment: you gave me a good solution but i want it to find the recent stable version and download it without me putting the version even if i use ansible to make it happen is it possible ?

Comment: Nginx does not provied a one link directly to stable version. You have to get the version. Another solution but not a good solution on the long term is to parse the html of the download page to get the link automatically.